# Is "baggage" as "portable military equipment" a technical or an old-fashioned term?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, register

According to dictionaries, one of the meanings of "baggage" is "an army's portable equipment". But I wonder if it is a technical or an old-fashioned term. I'm not sure if native speakers are generally familiar with this meaning of the word.

Comment: Only those interested in military history, I suspect.

Comment: @KateBunting - And yet it's not been tagged as a "technical" term in dictionaries!

Comment: I meant that it's an old-fashioned term, not that it's technical language. It goes back to the time when armies marched on foot and carried their equipment in horse-drawn wagons.  According to (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_(military) , what used to be 'baggage trains'  in the British Army became the Royal Army Service Corps.

Comment: Modern military terminology would be "Gear" or simply "Equipment". Modern use of "Baggage" usually refers to extraneous, undesired, or unneccesary stuff.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a technical term but not an old-fashioned one:

> In military terminology, [baggage](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/baggage) is any equipment that can be carried or hauled along. This is the original definition, from the Old French baggage, "military equipment," from bague, for "bag or bundle."(Vocabulary.com)

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/baggage) lists as second, out of three,  the sense of military equipment, but they don’t define it  as archaic like other definitions such as  prostitute.

Comment: The 18th and 19th century use of "baggage" generally would seem to mean "items not needed immediately on the journey": these could actually be items carried by an individual on a quite short journey. For example the Scottish folk song Jenny Nettles which was collected, if not partly written, by Burns contains a description of a young woman dismissed from her place in service because she had had a child out of wedlock as having "fee and bountieth in her lap, bag and baggage on her back and baby in her oxter".